# How to display all users on the server/computer with a Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting and learning as I go along. I am basically trying to display all the users that may be on that specific server or computer by doing:

```
echo %USERNAME%
```

Is this enough to display all the local users or will it just display one local user?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Home version of Windows?  If so, then your options are more limited - see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1440493/how-to-get-query-command-on-windows-10).  You should still be able to use PowerShell, or download another option.  But in other versions of Windows you can use QUSER.

To check a remote computer with QUSER:

```
QUERY USER /SERVER:ComputerName
```

Return something such as this:

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 RemoteUserID          console             1  Active      none   4/29/2022 6:14 AM
```

To see options, type:

```
QUSER /?
```

Comment: I am running the batch script using wine downloaded on my ubuntu. Is query user a batch script command ?

Comment: I have displayed the username, but idk if i will be able to display all the users using echo %USERNAME% . I have no way of testing either, so i am confused if that command will display all the active users

Comment: @quarantine_code, I'm sorry, QUERY is an executable command that almost certainly will not be available in your situation.  As for %USERNAME%, it only tells you who is currently logged in, but will not give you any info about other people logged in.  You might try downloading PSLoggedOn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psloggedon

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic useraccount get name
```

If you want to delete the first line

```
wmic useraccount get name | findstr /l /v Name
```